# ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

For some reason I get the following error ***only*** when I open up a nested `webdriver` instance. No idea what is happening here.

I am using *Windows 10,* *geckodriver 0.21.0,* and *Python 3.7.*

***ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053]***

```
An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

***Part of Script That Is Working Fine***

```
tab_backers = ff.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@gogo-test="backers_tab"]')

try:
    funding_backers_count = int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, str(tab_backers.text))))
except ValueError:
    funding_backers_count = 0

if funding_backers_count > 0:
    tab_backers.click()

    see_more_backers = WebDriverWait(ff, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//ui-view//a[text()="See More Backers"]'))
    )
    clicks = 0
    while clicks < 0:
        clicks += 1
        ff.WebDriverWait(ff, 5).until(
            see_more_backers.click()
        )

    for container in ff.find_elements_by_xpath('//ui-view//div[@class="campaignBackers-pledge ng-scope"]'):
        backers_profile = container.find_elements_by_xpath('./*/div[@class="campaignBackers-pledge-backer-details"]/a')
        if len(backers_profile) > 0:
            backers_profile = backers_profile[0].get_attribute('href') 
        else:
            backers_profile = 'Unknown'
        backers_name = safe_encode(container.find_element_by_xpath('(./*/div[@class="campaignBackers-pledge-backer-details"]/*)[1]').text)
        backers_timestamp = container.find_element_by_xpath('./*/div[@class="campaignBackers-pledge-backer-details"]/div[contains(@class, "campaignBackers-pledge-backer-details-note")]').text
        backers_contribution = container.find_element_by_xpath('./*//*[contains(@class, "campaignBackers-pledge-amount-bold")]').text
        if backers_contribution != 'Private':
            backers_contribution = int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, str(backers_contribution))))
        if backers_profile != 'Unknown':
```

***Part of Script Causing System to Abort Connection***

```
            _ff = create_webdriver_instance()
            _ff.get(backers_profile)
            _ff.quit()
```

***Traceback***

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Anthony\Desktop\test.py", line 271, in <module>
    backers_profile = container.find_elements_by_xpath('./*/div[@class="campaignBackers-pledge-backer-details"]/a')
  File "C:\Users\Anthony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 381, in find_elements_by_xpath
    return self.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Users\Anthony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 680, in find_elements
    {"using": by, "value": value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\Anthony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 628, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\Anthony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 318, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "C:\Users\Anthony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 472, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "C:\Users\Anthony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 495, in _request
    self._conn.request(method, parsed_url.path, body, headers)
  File "C:\Users\Anthony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1229, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Anthony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1275, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Anthony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1224, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Anthony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1055, in _send_output
    self.send(chunk)
  File "C:\Users\Anthony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 977, in send
    self.sock.sendall(data)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

**geckodriver.log**

Here it is in a [codepen,](https://codepen.io/tOkyO1/pen/mjxxRN?editors=0010) since it is wayyy too long!

***create_webdriver_instance Function***

```
def create_webdriver_instance():
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('-headless')
    try:
        ua_string = random.choice(ua_strings)
        profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
        profile.set_preference('general.useragent.override', ua_string)
        return webdriver.Firefox(profile) # profile, firefox_options=options
    except IndexError as error:
        print('\nSection: Function to Create Instances of WebDriver\nCulprit: random.choice(ua_strings)\nIndexError: {}\n'.format(error))
        return webdriver.Firefox() # firefox_options=options
```

**Does anybody have any idea whatsoever what might be causing the connection to abort?**

Comment: Could you show please what `create_webdriver_instance()` does?

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov of course. i'll add it right now

Comment: What does the geckodriver.log file say?

Comment: @K.Dackow first thing when i wake up tomorrow ill run that part of the script again and post the geckodriver.log and ill send you a msg to notify u

Comment: @K.Dackow ok, ive added the geckodriver.log in a codepen since it puts me way over the character limit. tbh i have no idea what i am or should be looking for in it :/

Comment: I'm not entirely sure either, but usually search for ERROR or EXCEPTION within it to try and diagnose the issue!

Comment: @K.Dackow that's what i was thinking. there are numerous errors throughout it, so when i get some time i'm gon have to take a closer look

Answer (score 14):

This error message...

```
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

...implies that the initialization of a new **WebBrowsing Session** i.e. **Firefox Browser** session was aborted.

---

### <sub>An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine</sub>

As per your code attempt the error is clearly coming out `create_webdriver_instance()` function which contains:

```
try:
    ua_string = random.choice(ua_strings)
    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_preference('general.useragent.override', ua_string)
    return webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```

And:

```
except IndexError as error:
    print('\nSection: Function to Create Instances of WebDriver\nCulprit: random.choice(ua_strings)\nIndexError: {}\n'.format(error))
    return webdriver.Firefox()
```

So it is not exactly clear from which function you are facing this issue among `return webdriver.Firefox(profile)` or `webdriver.Firefox()`.

Perhaps a closer look at the logs within [codepen](https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/support/server-support-and/1883490-please-help-java-io-ioexception-an-established) suggests the error is coming out from **`webdriver.Firefox(profile)`**.

---

### Reasons

There can be multiple reason behind this error:

- Presence of *anti-virus softwares*.
- Firewall blocking the ports.
- Network Configuration.
- Problem can be caused by [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).
- Due to enabling of HTTP keep-alive connections

---

### Solution

The initial step would be find out if any software is blocking the connection to/from the server in your computer. Apart from that the probable solutions are:

- Disable *anti-virus softwares*.
- Disable *firewall*.
- Ensure that /etc/hosts on your system contains the following entry:

  ```
  127.0.0.1   localhost.localdomain localhost
  ```
- As per [Connection was aborted by the software in your host machine](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy/issues/303) you need to allow localhost routes like `http://localhost:8080/reactive-commands`
- As per [Keep-Alive connection to geckodriver 0.21.0 dropped after 5s of inactivity without re-connection using Selenium Python client](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1304)

  - > **AutomatedTester**: This issue is not because we are not connected at the time of doing a request. If that was the issue we would be getting a httplib.HTTPConnection exception being thrown. Instead a BadStatusLine is thrown when we do a connection and close it and try parse the response. Now this could be the python stdlib bug, httplib bug or selenium bug. A Python client to replace urllib with something else that does not exhibit the same defect with Keep-Alive connections is *WIP*.
  - > **andreastt**: The geckodriver team is working on extending the server-side timeout value to something more reasonable. As I said, this would help mitigate this issue but not fundamentally fix it. In any case it is true that five seconds is probably too low to get real benefit from persistent HTTP connections, and that increasing it to something like 60 seconds would have greater performance.

---

### Conclusion

**`Selenium 3.14.0`** has just been released. If you are affected by this issue please upgrade accordingly.

---

References:

- [Flask broken pipe with requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12591760/flask-broken-pipe-with-requests)
- [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)
- [Connection was aborted by the software in your host machine](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy/issues/303)
- [[WinError 10053] with the 0.21.0](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1305)
- [Keep-Alive connection to geckodriver 0.21.0 dropped after 5s of inactivity without re-connection using Selenium Python client](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1304)
- [Support keep alive connections](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1468398)
- [Struct hyper::server::Server](https://hyper.rs/hyper/0.8.0/hyper/server/struct.Server.html#method.keep_alive)
- [Urllib3](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/6103)

Answer (score 9):

As [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinSock/windows-sockets-error-codes-2) says:

> Software caused connection abort. An established connection was
>   aborted by the software in your host computer, possibly due to a data
>   transmission time-out or protocol error.

Possible reasons:

1. Timeout or other network-level error.
2. Network connection died
3. Firewall closed the connection because it was open too long
4. Connection was closed before process has been finished
5. AntiVirus blocks the connection

and etc.

Also try to downgrade `geckodriver 0.21.0` to `geckodriver 0.20.1`. You can download it [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.20.1). It seems to be a problem with `geckodriver 0.21.0` https://stackoverflow.com/a/51236719/8625512

***PS:***

```
options.add_argument('-headless')
```

should be:

```
options.add_argument('--headless')
```

Comment: can you take a look at the `geckodriver.log` i just posted to the codepen in my question?!?! im not sure what to look for in it??

Comment: Could you please provide a code where you are creating a nested webdriver. Also please describe the process. Are you closing the parent webdriver before child is finished?

Comment: i already provided the code where i create the "nested" webdriver. `_ff` is the nested webdriver, and no i'm not closing the parent (`ff`) before i close `_ff`

Answer (score 6):

This problem happened to me and as the error was intermittent, I initially believed that it was some firewall or antivirus problem, but it was much simpler.

I had a form that was being submitted twice when the SEND button was clicked. The button was set to type="submit" and a javascript code submitted this form when this button was clicked. I changed the button to type="button" and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 3):

**Another reason:**
When a page served by python is loading, user may *cancel* the loading before transmission is complete, by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> or by clicking 'X'(Stop loading this page button). This is usually done when the server is slow.
E.g. if user navigates to your page and Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> before the image is fully loaded, this error will occur. In that case, you have to *Handle it*.

Answer (score 2):

Windows has implemented Controlled folder access, which is to block un-authorized app to access your important files(means almost anything installed by windows). This is to prevent data encryption and ransom by malware.

Windows will pop-out notification if it blocks any app.

You can allow apps/programs access through Controlled folder access.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem with a browser configuration in Firefox: Go to **Settings** -> **general** and scroll down to **network configuration**. in the window that opens I go to the end I selected **DNS PROXY USE SOCKS** and activated **DNS over HTTPS**. I chose all three options available.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. The issue is happening if the same request is sending multiple times to the server.

This problem happened to me and as the error was intermittent, I initially believed that it was some firewall or antivirus problem, but it was much simpler.

I had a form that was being submitted twice when the SEND button was clicked. The button was set to type="submit" and a javascript code submitted this form when this button was clicked. I changed the button to type="button" and the problem was solved.

Comment: glad to hear that

Answer (score 0):

**Another reason in browser (not webdriver)**: An extension that doesn't update frequently. In my case this issue was solved when disabling an extension that had some deprecated code. Try on an incognito window for a quick check.

Comment: there were extensions running in your webdriver instance?! didnt even know this was possible o: chrome? firefox?

Comment: No, I'm sorry I didn't clarify. I got this error in the browser's console not in a webdriver.