# Solving the ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] without messing around with the Windows Defender and Firewall

Tags: django, windows

The infamous `ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053]` error:

> ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

has obviously caused a whole lot of headaches when searching the internet. There are many workarounds suggested on different forums. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51697893/4999991) suggests that antivirus (i.e., Windows Defender) and the firewall should be disabled, which doesn't seem like a wise idea. And [this post](https://github.com/django-helpdesk/django-helpdesk/issues/621#issuecomment-573320519) suggests adding:

> port 8000 to allowed rules for both incoming and outgoing traffic

which I prefer not to do, simply because I don't know the implications of messing around with the firewall. The [same post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51697893/4999991), however, also suggests adding the line:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost.localdomain localhost
```

to the `/etc/hosts`, which according to [this post](https://superuser.com/a/525691/588662) should be `\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` on Windows OS. However, doing so (adding the above line to the `hosts` file) did not help with the above error. So my questions, as the title implies, is that if there is a way to solve the said problem or circumvent it, without messing around with the Windows Defender and firewall, and jeopardizing the system's safety/security?

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem, and I did several searches on the internet, but in the end probably the solution, for me, was easier than expected: that error comes out when a resource is not found.

In my case it couldn't find some *.js* files, due to wrong `<link ..>` directives (`static` was not used).

Fixed this, the problem was greatly mitigated, but sometimes it came back, and always after a `Not Found: /favicon.ico` error.

Doing other research I discovered that browsers often make a default request to have a  `favicon.ico` file in the root, which obviously isn't there.

By adding a redirect `url (r '^ favicon \ .ico $', RedirectView.as_view (url = '/ static / images / favicon.ico')),` in the file urls.py, this problem is also solved.

Now the problem seems to be gone, so I assume it was derived, at least in this case, from resources not correctly found by Django.

I hope my experience could help.