# Django Error of established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

> Problem after running my Django project on the local server I'm getting such error shown below. Please help me to solve the problem.

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 174, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 182, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine```
````

Comment: Have you tried these suggestions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51697893/13290801?