# python3.9 websocket error (discord gateway)

Tags: python, websocket, discord

```
import websocket #pip install websocket-client
import json
import threading
import time

token_file = open("token.txt", "r")
token_read = token_file.read()
token_list = token_read.split()
token_file.close()
print(token_list)

def send_json_request(ws, request):
    ws.send(json.dumps(request))

def recieve_json_response(ws):
    response = ws.recv()
    if response:
        return json.loads(response)

def heartbeat(interval, ws):
    print('Heartbeat begin')
    while True:
        time.sleep(interval)
        heartbeatJSON = {
            "op": 1,
            "d": "null"
        }
        send_json_request(ws, heartbeatJSON)
        print("Heartbeat sent")

for index , v in enumerate(token_list):
    ws = websocket.WebSocket()
    ws.connect('wss://gateway.discord.gg/?v=6&encording=json')
    event = recieve_json_response(ws)

    heartbeat_interval = event['d']['heartbeat_interval'] / 1000
    threading._start_new_thread(heartbeat, (heartbeat_interval, ws))


    pis=1
    payload = {
        'op': 2,
        "d": {
            "token": v,
            "properties": {
                "$os": "windows",
                "$browser": "chrome",
                "$device": 'pc'
            }
        }
    }
    try:
        send_json_request(ws, payload)
    except:
        index += 1
        print(index, "error")
```

```
Exception ignored in thread started by: <function heartbeat at 0x00000236C458D3A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\test\websoket.py", line 38, in heartbeat
    send_json_request(ws, heartbeatJSON)
  File "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\test\websoket.py", line 16, in send_json_request
    ws.send(json.dumps(request))
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\websocket\_core.py", line 282, in send
    return self.send_frame(frame)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\websocket\_core.py", line 310, in send_frame
    l = self._send(data)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\websocket\_core.py", line 514, in _send
    return send(self.sock, data)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\websocket\_socket.py", line 175, in send
    return _send()
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\websocket\_socket.py", line 152, in _send
    return sock.send(data)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 1173, in send
    return self._sslobj.write(data)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053]
```

**works fine for some time But I get an error and the connection is closed
What did I do wrong?**

Answer (score 1):

The key is in the final error message in the stack trace: `ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053]`. You can find an answer to that question here: [ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51562067/connectionabortederror-winerror-10053-an-established-connection-was-aborted-b)

In future posts, please include the source code directly in the post rather than an image and please enter the error output in ``` format so that it is monospaced.